# Content Query Multiple columns within each header

Tags: content-query-web-part

Does anyone know of a way to enable groupings on a content query web part which displays results in 3 columns? I have been able to create 3 columns display But the results are all shown only after all header groupings.

E.g. target: 
———-group/header 1———-
-result1- -result2- -result3-
-result4- -result5- -result6-
———-group/header 2————---
-result7- -result8-

E.g. what I got: 
————header 1———-
————-header 2———
-result1- -result-2- -result3-
-result4- -result5- -result6-
-result7- -result8-

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!